# Four way handshake in 802.11

Tags: security, handshake, wifi, wpa

I know that the main goal of four way handshake in 802.11 is to

1. Derive the PTK from the PMK
2. Verify the cipher suite communicated in the beacon and associate request frame
3. Communicate the group keys from AP to the station

I have referred this [site](https://www.wifi-professionals.com/2019/01/4-way-handshake) and I want to know,

Can the four way handshake in 802.11 be accomplished with fewer messages if yes then how and if no then why not ?

Answer (score 0):

So in this case you can ask yourself a question : if you try to reduce any of the message , will either of the system still have the required information to generate the session keys?
And you will get the answer , which is : NO.